# Create an Azure website deployment slot - REST API sample

Tags: azure, web

I am trying to find a sample on how to create an Azure Website (web app) deployment slot via the REST API. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Azure Management libraries to do this directly to the API. You can find the Libraries [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries) and a sample of how to use them [here](http://www.bradygaster.com/post/getting-started-with-the-windows-azure-management-libraries). An extra way to do it is use the Azure Resource Manager [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790568.aspx) directly.

Comment: Panagiotis,

We are not allowed to use anything pre-release, hence I cannot use the management library. Actually it has been pre-release for quite a long time.

Also, the Azure Resource Manager API does not appear to have functionality for websites but only for resource 'groups', subscriptions etc.

Hence, this was my question about how to do this with the current REST API.

Thanks!

Comment: The libraries are not prerelease, I don't get what you mean by that. They're version 2.0.0 already.

Comment: If I go to this site, I still see pre-release https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites/0.16.4-prerelease

Comment: This question still seems to be completely unanswered. @etowah_man , did you ever find an actual solution via REST?

Comment: As I mentioned on my original answer, you can call the ARM REST API and it will work fine. I strongly suggest using the libraries though. To find the exact payload and endpoint, you can go to resources.azure.com and explore the WebSites provider.